# Nicknames database

Tags: data-request, names

I'm interested in being able to identify a name like "Nick" as a short form of a name like "Nicholas" in a data set.

Is there any kind of open or somewhat standardized mapping of names and nicknames available? I am fine if it's limited to Western or American English names, but international data is even better.

Comment: how does this bounty work? i feel like my answer is good enough, but i'm sure it could be better. are you asking for more answers?

Comment: @albert, no, I'm not asking for more answers, but you obviously can edit existing answer, if you want. One just can't award an answer in first 24 hours after bounty assignment, even if the bounty reason is "award existing answer". Of course, if somebody will post another good answer today, I'll start another bounty. Current bounty is a share of [this one](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12649/16193).

Comment: ah, i guess i'm just confused at how bounties work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Nicknames and Diminutive Names Lookup (CSV)](https://github.com/carltonnorthern/nickname-and-diminutive-names-lookup)
[CSV, Database of Common Nicknames](https://danconnor.com/posts/4f65ea41daac4ed03100000f/csv_database_of_common_nicknames) and its GitHub Repository: [Common Nickname CSV (Database)](https://github.com/onyxrev/common_nickname_csv)
[Name to Nickname CSV](https://github.com/MrCsabaToth/SOEMPI/blob/master/openempi/conf/name_to_nick.csv) and [Nickname to Name CSV](https://github.com/MrCsabaToth/SOEMPI/blob/master/openempi/conf/nick_to_name.csv)

Comment: There's also this list that was extracted from US Census data: https://web.archive.org/web/20181022154748/https://deron.meranda.us/data/nicknames.txt

Comment: @glenviewjeff I'm wary to trust that list. It makes some weird choices like mapping "Sam" to Samuel but not Samantha, "Izzy" to Isadore but not Isabelle, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Two more [hypocorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocorism) (=diminutive form of a name) datasets:

- https://github.com/brianary/Lingua-EN-Nickname/blob/master/nicknames.txt
- https://github.com/jonathanhar/diminutives.db:

  - https://github.com/jonathanhar/diminutives.db/blob/master/female_diminutives.csv
  - https://github.com/jonathanhar/diminutives.db/blob/master/male_diminutives.csv

Related: large (160k) dataset of mames worldwide  https://github.com/philipperemy/name-dataset

Answer (score 3):

Wikidata has a nickname property https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1449

which can be used with given names https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q202444 or https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q82799

which you can query with SPARQL https://query.wikidata.org

This approach may give you a more "real-life" dataset, and statistics about how many nicknames map back to given names, etc.

Comment: This is a great idea, but when I tried some example queries at https://w.wiki/4qa2, a lot of the nicknames I got were weird. Like "The Little Assassin" (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q233339). Maybe with some filtering though this could be useful?